# About PolSDP software for SAR processing

Tags: remote-sensing, radar, insar, vegetation-index

Can anybody help me to find PolSDP software or provide a link from where I can download.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [tour]. Where have you looked prior to posting here?  Can you [edit] your question to include perhaps a link to the home page of `PolSDP` ?

Answer (score 1):

My search on the web for PolsDP turned up this answer first.

> PolsDP is a Polarimetric SAR data processing software being developed
>   at the CSRE, IIT Bombay, under the sponsorship of SAC, ISRO. It aims
>   to be a toolbox for PolSAR data processing, allowing the user to
>   easily run various steps like exporting data from SLC files,
>   processing, decomposition of T3 matrix and C2 matrix, classification,
>   geocoding, geophysical parameter inversion, signatures, target
>   detection, etc. The software can be made available freely through SAC, ISRO.

Contact the author of the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233990542_Software_Development_for_Polarimetric_SAR_Data_PolSDP), Shaunak Dem CSRE, IIT-Bombay, Powai, Mumbai-400076, shaunakde@iitb.ac.in

or go to SAC, http://www.sac.gov.in/sacwebi/sacHomePage.iface

Comment: Could u please tell me more detail about how to download PolSDP software from SAC? I had tried it but unable to see it and download. It is very important for my research work. Thanks in advance.